# Display message box while closing the window by using closing option (X) of the window

Tags: flex3

Can anyone help me how to display message/alert box when user clicks  Close option (X) of the window in flex ?

Like in html we can handle it by using,

window.onbeforeunload = function(){return "Are you sure you want to Exit";}

Is there anything in Flex similar to "window.onbeforeunload" of HTML which can handle Close option (X) of the window ?

If not, can anyone help me to handle this with sample code.?

In my mxml i have not used any kind of , etc. 
My flex screen is opened from a jsp page through a hyper link and i dont want to use any window related tags. It is normal screen with min, max and close option.

Thanks,

Anand.

Answer (score 0):

Use  ExternalInterface.addCallback and from JavaScript call the AS function you want to run on close.
However I do not think you can block the browser from closing this way as it would be a security hole.

Another thing to note here is that the code in the function should run fast or you may risk not having it all done before the browser closes.

All clients work should be done before close so a method like this wouldn't be needed.

A more appropriate method would be to create some kind of session for the user and store the data server side as the client works.

Unless of course your are just trying to make some kind of hack app.